# Partial-Payment:Is there anyway we can create Payment and Transaction without creating invoice?

Tags: payment-methods, payment, payment-gateway, partial-payments

I am trying to implement Partial Payment in the Magento. I kind of implementing it, in a way by creating multiple invoices (the idea is creating invoice quantity based on the amount paid). But, the current method involved a lot of factional values and their calculations.

I am, thinking the cleaner way is accepting payments and creating invoices only at the last payment.

So I would like to know if there is any other way we can accept "Payment Amount" and record it in `sales_order`, `sales_order_payment`, and `sales_payment_transaction`(not sure whether Payment touches any other tables).

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

No,

You can not create payment without creating an Invoice. But Magento Provides a facility to create a Partial Invoice.

For Example: User have added 2 products and place an order. and Admin can create partial Invoice. So 2 Invoices will be created.

Comment: Thank you, I am doing same thing only, just looking for other possibilities.